# Does the functor $X:[n] \rightarrow C$ preseve colimit?

Tags: category-theory

Let $[n]$ be the category of integers $\{0, \ldots, n \}$ totally ordered by $\le$ (its morphisms). Let $X:[n] \rightarrow C$ be a functor to another category $C$. Then

> is $X(n)$ a colimit of the diagram given by $X$?

---

This seems to be deceptively true:

$X(n)$ is a cocone, with $id:X(n) \rightarrow X(n)$ be the leg at $n$.

If $Y$ is a cocone then there is a morphism $y_n:X(n) \rightarrow Y$. This is our morphism from the cocones too.

This is unique as any such cocone morphism $y:X(n) \rightarrow Y$ must satisfy, $y \circ id= y_n$.

Comment: If a category $C$ has a terminal object $t$, colimiting a diagram with domain $C$ coincides with evaluating the diagram at $t$.

Comment: You mean the terminal object is the colimit of the diagram?

Comment: The value of the diagram at the terminal object is the colimit, CL.